# Using CodeFirst with EF struggling to get a dropdownlist to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to develop a fairly simple app, for use in the office and for my own training purposes.

At present I am a little stuck with getting a dropdownlist to appear.

**The Data Structure**

table: **Resource**
ResourceID (int) (PK)
Name (varchar)
Description (varchar)
ResourceTypeID (int) (FK)

table: **REsourceType**
ResourceTypeID (int) (PK)
Title (varchar)
Description (varchar)

So a simple datastructure. Each Resource is of one type, but each type can be applied to many resources. I have 3 model files:

**Resource**

```
namespace ESF_ResourceManager.Models
{
    public class Resource
    {
        [Key]
        public int ResourceID { get; set; } 

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a name for the resource")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="Resource name is too long, 50 characters or less")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please neter a meaningful description of this resource")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please specify the turn around time in minutes")]
        public int TurnAroundTime { get; set; }

        // links resource to a resource type
        public int ResourceTypeID { get; set; }


         //public virtual ICollection<ResourceType> ResourceTypes { get; set; }
        // public virtual ResourceType ResourceTypeID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ResourceType**

```
namespace ESF_ResourceManager.Models
{
    public class ResourceType
    {
        [Key]
        public int ResourceTypeID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a title for the resource type")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Resource type name is too long, 50 characters or less")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a meaningful description for the resource type")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
        //public virtual Resource Resource {get; set;}
    }
}
```

**ResourceAdminManager**

```
namespace ESF_ResourceManager.Models
{
    public class ResourceAdminManager : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ResourceType> ResourceTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have developed the views and controllers for both the Resource and ResourceType. ResourceType is really straight forward and that set is working just fine. The trouble I am having is understanding how to get the Resource views for Create and Edit to display the options for ResourceType in a drop down list and how to display the title of the ResourceType not the ID in all the views.

I have spent quite some time looking over this and have not yet found anything the aids my understanding. So, please as a newbie take it easy with me and I'm sure I'll get there with your help.

Many thanks
nathj07

Comment: What UI technology are you working with?

Comment: This is just aspx view not razr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View Model - CreateResourceViewModel.cs:

```
public class CreateResourceViewModel
{
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ResourceType> ResourceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Controller (ResourceController.cs):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var dbContext = new ResourceDbContext();

    var model = new CreateResourceViewModel
                    {
                        Resource = new Resource(),
                        ResourceTypes = dbContext.ResourceTypes.ToList()
                    };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateResourceViewModel model)
{
    // process model

    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

View (Create.cshtml):

```
@model ResourceMVC.Models.CreateResourceViewModel

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Resource.ResourceTypeId)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Resource.ResourceTypeId, 
                          new SelectList(Model.ResourceTypes, "ResourceTypeId", "Title"),
                          "-- Select Resource Type --")
</div>
```

This will bind the `Id` of the selected `ResourceType` to the `ResourceTypeId` of the new `Resource` object when it is POSTed back to the `ResourceController`.

Comment: Thank you for this. This has really solved my problem. The key now is to find out if I really understand what is going on enough to repeat this type of thing with some other tables.  If I get stuck I'll be sure to head back over here.

Comment: Sorry about this, I'll add a proper new post on the bottom. Sorry

Comment: The only problem I found with this solution is that EF would create new rows in the child table instead of picking up the existing row. No idea why

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really associated the ResourceTypes to a Resource yet.

Add to Resource:

```
[Include]
[Association("GiveItAName", "ResourceID", "ResourceTypeID")]
public EntityCollection<ResourceType> ResourceTypes { get; set; }
```

or

```
[Include]
[Association("GiveItAName", "ResourceID", "ResourceTypeID")]
public ResourceType ResourceType { get; set; }
```

Use [ForeignKey] attribute to mark the ID fields as FK field.

Then you should be able to do things like `MyResource.ResourceType.Title` Use Fiddler and the WCF Binary add-in to verify that EF is returning the objects and properly including the child elements.

Comment: @dulaca if the navigation properties are implemented correctly, or the foreign key is not composite, EF already knows how to implement the relationship and doesn't need the `[ForeignKey]` attribute.